# Add class to Menu Block UL unique to each Menu Block instance?

Tags: routes, blocks

I've seen lots of answers, but they only allow you to add classes to all Menu Blocks, or to specific Menus.

I have multiple menu blocks with the same menu behind them (1st level block, 2nd level block, etc.)

I need each menu block to have a unique class based upon the name of the Menu Block. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your theme changes the usual behavior then each of your menu blocks will have its own unique ID so you can use CSS like this (note the ID/class I used here might not be the ones you have to use, they're just an example):

```
#block-menu-block-2 ul.menu
```

This way you don't have to worry about overriding the markup of the menu to add classes in.

Comment: I was hoping to have a way to use the UL, since I stripped the wrapper div already (I hate Drupal's DOM bloat).

Comment: There is a way to do that, I just put this as an alternative.